# amp-form verification doesn't work, even with official documentation code

Tags: amp-html, amp-form

I'm trying to implement custom field verification on an `amp-form` component, but all my efforts are in vain.

Although the `XHR request returns a valid JSON`, it doesn't invalidate the field and there is no error message displayed.

I tried the code from the official documentation: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/?referrer=ampproject.org#verification with no luck.

Turned to the Git code sample: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/main/examples/forms.amp.html and still nothing.

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the full code: [AMP Playground](https://playground.amp.dev/?mode=Responsive#share=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)

Here are my script attachements:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-anim" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-anim-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-latest.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
```

And here is my form:

```
<form
method="post"
action-xhr="https://ampscript.xyz/wp-content/uploads/demo/verify"
verify-xhr="https://ampscript.xyz/wp-content/uploads/demo/verify"  
custom-validation-reporting="as-you-go"
target="_blank"
>
<fieldset>
    <label>
        <span>Email</span>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
        <span visible-when-invalid="customError" validation-for="email">That email is already taken</span>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <span>Zip Code</span>
        <input type="tel" name="zip" id="zip" required pattern="[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?">
    </label>
    <br>
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>
<div submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <p>Congratulations! You are registered with {{email}}</p>
    </template>
</div>
<div submit-error>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        {{#verifyErrors}}                
            <p>{{message}}</p>
        {{/verifyErrors}}
        {{^verifyErrors}}                
            <p>Something went wrong. Try again later?</p>
        {{/verifyErrors}}        
    </template>
</div>
</form>
```

The returned JSON is:

```
{
    "verifyErrors": [
        {
            "name": "email",
            "message": "That email is already taken."
        },
        {
            "name": "zip",
            "message": "The city and zip do not match."
        }
    ]
}
```

Full code can be found in [AMP Playground](https://playground.amp.dev/?mode=Responsive#share=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)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple! The response header had a status 200.

Apparently, the script checks the status of the request before it checks the JSON itself.

Here is the verification endpoint in PHP for future reference:

```
<?php

    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]. '');
    header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin');
    header('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: '.$_GET["__amp_source_origin"].'');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

    $response = array(
        "verifyErrors" => array(
            array(
                "name" => "email",
                "message" => "That email is already taken."
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "zip",
                "message" => "The city and zip do not match."
            )
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```